# Why my web.xml file is showing in table format

Tags: eclipse

Why my web.xml file is showing in table format with Node and Column, i want to view it as default format and edit it. Please help me

[web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB2RV.png)

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of the editor are tabs for **Design** and **Source**. Click on **Source**. It will open in that tab from then on.

Answer (score 0):

- At package explorer right click on your created xml file in your project.
- Choose 'open with' option there.
- And click on generic text editor

You will have the default template.